# Is there any CSS workaround for position sticky and overflow of parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm struggling with an issue which is not working sticky position if I have overflow property set to auto on a parent element. I've tried many of things like adding an extra wrapper for the element with sticky property, using clip instead of auto but none of these helped. I found a solution with some js script applied but I would rather prefer to use pure CSS if that is possible.

```
     <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="left">
        <div className="header" />
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <div className="header">Blablabla blablabla blabla</div>
        <div className="table"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And css:

```
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.right {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}

.table {
  width: 2000px;
}
```

I've created small example to playaround:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-yrmmde

What I want to achive is to have right header sticky aswell but the right container should be scrollable on X axis at the same time

Comment: Post debugging details in the question itself to be self-containing. External resources are neither an acceptable, suitable nor allowed replacement.

Comment: That is no **Angular** code! It is **React**

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonCounter } from './components/ButtonCounter';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="left">
        <div className="header" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="header">Blablabla blablabla blabla</div>
        <div className="right"></div>
        <div className="table" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.left {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.right {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.table {
  width: 2000px;
}
```

You were placing your header inside the right div. I removed it from the inside and gave them z-index based on their priority. Hope this is the solution you are looking for.